# What hash algorithm is used for passwords stored in shadow in 11.10?

Tags: password

I'm a little bit confused if it's MD5 or SHA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 8.10, SHA-512.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features

in particular for Ubuntu 11.10

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man3/crypt.3.html